# 403 error on Lighthouse3D's web

Tags: web, http-status-code-403

I am really pissed about the fact, that Lighthouse tutorial web (**http://www.lighthouse3d.com/**) is throwing me 403error forbidden. Don't you know what they are doing, or will it be in the future online? I helluva need it to my school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rudolf said, the website is experiencing problems on server side.

But, if you want to check something urgently here is a useful link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130216083928/http://www.lighthouse3d.com/

Comment: duuuuuuuuuuuude, you're my savior!!! thanks you very very very and much more very much

Answer (score 2):

It might be that they do something on their side , or if site requires some kind of auth , they didn't provided solution nor explanataion. Tried to load it , same happens. Might be that Apache server and mods has to be restarted or fixed. I got many times 403 error , like when I try to open www.openlicenser.org which also throws this error , and it wasn't fixed yet , I think.

Comment: Sometimes , they don't , if they have subscrption , or You have contact email , You should ask them what is going on , and when do they plan to fix it , this way , they will get a lot of angry users and that isn't way if they want to have a good site. Besides , if You know what You are looking for , just try google , it may be available on other site , never depend on only one source , that's little advice from me.